# Nashorn: Strict equality comparing BigDecimal with number

Tags: javascript, java, nashorn

In Oracle's JDK 1.8.0_121, within Nashorn (the JavaScript engine embedded in the JDK), `new BigDecimal(1.0) === 1` is `false`, and `new BigDecimal(1.0) == 1` is `true`:

Using JDK 1.8.0_121's `jjs` (Nashorn REPL):

```
jjs> var BigDecimal = Java.type("java.math.BigDecimal")
jjs> var bd = new BigDecimal(1.0)
jjs> bd
1
jjs> bd === 1.0
false
jjs> bd == 1.0
true
```

Using JDK 1.8.0_74's `jjs`:

```
jjs> var BigDecimal = Java.type("java.math.BigDecimal")
jjs> var bd = new BigDecimal(1.0)
jjs> bd
1
jjs> bd === 1.0
true
jjs> bd == 1.0
true
```

Is this a known tightening of strictness rules for equality in Nashorn? Is there an explicit specification of the `===` strict equality operator in Nashorn that can explain this behavior and hopefully the change in behavior?

Or is this a regression in the JDK?

Comment: Looks more like a bug *fix* to me. An object instance should never be `===` to a number.

Comment: Yeah, it could be a bug fix, but I couldn't find reference to it in any release notes. My assumption was that the prior behavior was to allow any subclass of `java.lang.Number` to be `===` to a number (including BigDecimal), but there is precious little detail on what is "correct" for Nashorn.

Comment: Well note that in plain JavaScript, `new Number(1) === 1` is `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an intentional change in JDK 1.8.0_101 and later, documented in [JDK-8143896](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143896). The handling of strict equality must be intentional, since it is called out with a [test case that covers BigDecimal being compared to an integer](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/nashorn/rev/bfc671539e50#l15.110).

This isn't called out in the JDK release notes, but it can be confirmed as an intentional change in behavior.